# chartiq in nestjs Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: node.js, nestjs, chartiq

I'm trying to use chartiq study calculator in NestJs and it throws the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: A:\projects\chartiq-service\chartiq-service\node_modules\chartiq\modules\studycalc\study-calculator.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of A:\projects\chartiq-service\chartiq-service\node_modules\chartiq\modules\studycalc\study-calculator.js from A:\projects\chartiq-service\chartiq-service\dist\chartiq\services\chartiq.service.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename study-calculator.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from A:\projects\chartiq-service\chartiq-service\node_modules\chartiq\package.json.
```

how can I fix this?
I'm only trying to import it and App keep throw this exception

Comment: did you tried to follow what the error suggests?

Comment: @MicaelLevi yes actually chartiq work in pure node app without any problem but in nestjs, it throws the above error. I ask chartiq support team and they said they don't use any require() in their code and it's all ES6 standard